# Products similar to Heroku Connect?

Tags: heroku-connect

Are there any similar real-time integration services that support other databases?

I'm not looking for opinions on products, rather looking for a list of options.

Answer (score 1):

One option to put on your list is Sesame Software's [Relational Junction](http://sesamesoftware.com/relational-junction/salesforce-integration/).